# Code to delete a row in one Sub works but the other doesn't. "Delete Method of Range class failed"

Tags: vba, excel

I have several sub's that use this exact same code, but this one returns

Run-time error '1004':

Delete method of Range class failed

```
drill.Range("48:48").Delete
```

in the others it works just fine, but in this one it does not

```
Sub Drill_Log_Undo()
'
'takes the last submited drill log and places it back into the submission     line
'

'Unprotects Drill Log
    Worksheets("Drill Log").Unprotect "Welcome1"

'Declares Variables
    Dim drill As Worksheet: Set drill = Worksheets("Drill Log")
    Dim start_joint As Range: Set start_joint = drill.Range("C48")

    Dim start_time As Range: Set start_time = drill.Range("F48")
    Dim info As Range: Set info = drill.Range("G48:S48")
    Dim tool_used As Range: Set tool_used = drill.Range("E48")
    Dim pass_type As Range: Set pass_type = drill.Range("D48")

    Dim x As Integer
        x = 0

'coppies the data to the submission line
        drill.Range("G37:S37").Value = drill.Range("G48:S48").Value 'to Multi
        drill.Range("G35:S35").Value = drill.Range("G48:S48").Value 'to Single

'changes the pass type to the previously entered pass type
        drill.Range("K10").Value = pass_type.Value

'determins whether the pass was multiple or single
    If drill.Range("F48") = Null Or drill.Range("F48") = "" Then

    'adds the end joint to the end joint submission cell
        drill.Range("C37").Value = drill.Range("C48")

    'counts the number of joints and removes them as it goes
        Do Until drill.Range("A59").Value = Null

            If start_time.Value = "" Or Null Then
```

Here is the line that throws the code

```
                drill.Range("48:48").Delete
```

End line

```
                x = x + 1
                Set start_time = drill.Range("F48")

            Else
                drill.Range("F37").Value = drill.Range("F48").Value

                Exit Do

            End If

        Loop

    'adds the last joint to the joint count and removes the joint row
        drill.Range("B37") = drill.Range("C48")
        x = x + 1
        drill.Range("48:48").Delete


Else




End If

'protects Drill Log
    Worksheets("Drill Log").Protect "Welcome1"

End Sub
```

I have tried different ways of declaring the variables, I have even tried specifically calling the code by calling the workbook and worksheet in the line.

Comment: Do you perhaps call a subroutine or function somewhere that re-protects the worksheet?

Comment: Yes this was in fact the problem. The code changed a cell that activated the sheet code and protected the sheet. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `drill.Range("48:48").Delete` with `drill.Rows("48").EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: This did not work. it gives the same error. I changed it to drill.range("48:48").Cut and it said that the sheet is protected.

Comment: ..wha? But you unprotect it at the start of the code..
The line that gets yellow is the `Range.Delete` one, right?

Comment: No.. wait.. Isnt the `Unprotect` portion also wrong? I am not familiar with protecting/unprotecting, but some research here has shown that you had to use it like `Worksheets("Drill Log").Unprotect Password:="Welcome1"`

Comment: I feel extremely stupid. I ran through the code stopping it line by line to see where it became protected again, and found that the line "drill.Range("K10").Value = pass_type.Value" activated some sheet code that ended in the protection of the sheet. thank you for trying to help me with my own stupidity. lol I'm going home.

Comment: It happens, dont take it to harsly :)